# My component doest not recieve props using react-redux with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, react-redux

Looks like my react component does not recieve props from redux store.
When i try to log props of my component, it shows

```
Object
history: {length: 3, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
location: {pathname: "/character", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "pbewpb"}
match: {path: "/character/:id?", url: "/character", isExact: true, params: {…}}
staticContext: undefined
state: undefined
requestCharacter: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

but in redux store it looks ok 
[Redux store screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbDAo.png)

And if i try to get some props like

```
{this.props.character.characterId}
```

it says that it`s undefined

**Here is my Character.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as CharactersStore from '../store/Characters';



type CharactersProps = CharactersStore.CharacterState
    & typeof CharactersStore.actionCreators
    & RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }>;

class CharacterInfo extends React.PureComponent<CharactersProps> {
    // This method is called when the component is first added to the document

    public componentDidMount()
    {
        this.ensureDataFetched();
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    // This method is called when the route parameters change
    public componentDidUpdate()
    {
        this.ensureDataFetched();
    }


    private ensureDataFetched()
    {
        const id = parseInt(this.props.match.params.id, 10) || 0;
        this.props.requestCharacter(id);
        console.log('logged props from enureDataFetched:');
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    public render()
    {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1 id="tabelLabel">HELLO FUCKIN WORLD</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server and working with URL parameters.</p>
                {this.renderCharacterHeader()}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
    private renderCharacterHeader()
    {
        return (
            <h1>
                <this.props.character.name}
            </h1>
            );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state: ApplicationState)
{
    return { state: state.characterState };
}


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
    CharactersStore.actionCreators // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
)(CharacterInfo as any);
```

Here is Character.ts

```
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';
import { AppThunkAction } from './';

// -----------------
// STATE - This defines the type of data maintained in the Redux store.

export interface CharacterState
{
    isLoading: boolean;
    id: number;
    character: Character;
}

export interface Character
{
    characterId: number;
    name: string;
    st: number;
    dx: number;
    iq: number;
    hp: number;
}


// -----------------
// ACTIONS - These are serializable (hence replayable) descriptions of state transitions.
// They do not themselves have any side-effects; they just describe something that is going to happen.

interface RequestCharacterAction
{
    type: 'REQUEST_CHARACTER';
    id: number;
}

interface RecieveCharacterAction
{
    type: 'RECIEVE_CHARACTER';
    character: Character;
}

// Declare a 'discriminated union' type. This guarantees that all references to 'type' properties contain one of the
// declared type strings (and not any other arbitrary string).
type KnownAction =  RequestCharacterAction | RecieveCharacterAction;

// ----------------
// ACTION CREATORS - These are functions exposed to UI components that will trigger a state transition.
// They don't directly mutate state, but they can have external side-effects (such as loading data).
export const actionCreators = {
    requestCharacter: (id: number): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) =>
    {
        const appState = getState();
        //if (appState && appState.characterState && id !== appState.characterState.character.id)
        {
            console.log('hello it worked');
            fetch('characters')
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<Character>)
                .then(data =>
                {
                    dispatch({ type: 'RECIEVE_CHARACTER',  character: data });
                });
            dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_CHARACTER', id: id });
        }
    }
};
// ----------------
// REDUCER - For a given state and action, returns the new state. To support time travel, this must not mutate the old state.
const unloadedState: CharacterState = { isLoading: false, id: -2, character: { characterId: -2, name: 'default', st: 10, dx: 10, iq:10, hp:10 }  };

export const reducer: Reducer<CharacterState> = (state: CharacterState | undefined, incomingAction: Action): CharacterState =>
{
    if (state === undefined)
    {
        return unloadedState;
    }

    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'REQUEST_CHARACTER':
            console.log('logged character from request_character');
            console.log(state.character);
            return {
                isLoading: true,
                id: state.id,
                character: state.character
            };
        case 'RECIEVE_CHARACTER':
            // Only accept the incoming data if it matches the most recent request. This ensures we correctly
            // handle out-of-order responses.
            console.log(action.character.name);
            if (action.character.characterId != state.character.characterId)
            {
                return {
                    isLoading: false,
                    id: action.character.characterId,
                    character: action.character
                };
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I tried to do it as it was shown in ASP.NET Core example of WeatherForecasts, but it doesn`t work for me :(